# Static front page in wordpress as categories

Tags: wordpress

[image]

Hey guys, I am trying to make a wordpress website like this one in the image.
But i cannot find a way to put categories as a static front page for the website.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

My website - thewikipedia.net
Theme link - https://wordpress.org/themes/mywiki/

Answer (score 0):

You've to include `wp_list_categories();` into your theme `index.php` file.
This will display all your categories on main page. 
 You can change style and align them according to your requirement using CSS.
By default, clicking a category link will then open the category page, which uses the `category.php` template, and this will show all the posts in that category.

Comment: isn't there any plugin for this?

Comment: Yes. Please follow the link below. http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-page-category